# ng2-chartjs2 Ionic 2 How to add options

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng2-charts

I did a small ionic2 project with ng2-chartjs2 charts based [on this project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-chartjs2). I need to add options and there's no documentation on how to add it. here is [my project repo](https://github.com/darthranjith/Ionic2-Chart)

**My options code snippet.**

```
options: Chart.Options[] = [{
    responsive: true, //red squiggly line here
    animation:false,
    defaultFontColor:"#666"
  }];
```

**home.html**

```
 <chart [labels]="labels" [data]="data" [options]="options" type="bar"></chart>
```

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Did you take a look at their demo? https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-chartjs2/blob/master/demo.ts Its pretty straight forward

Comment: Thanks @misha130 for the response. Yes, i used that demo to build my project and its working well, but i need to use options as shown in [this link](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-creating-a-chart-with-options). I know there's a way to use options tag as the options tag is represented by using the Chart.Options interface. But i don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1) main.ts

```
export class MainPage {

  options: any = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Restaurante", "Vestuário", "Lazer", "Eletrônico"],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dinheiro',
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#FDBC11',
          '#ee4250',
          '#02A4C0',
          '#229f37'
        ],
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        position: 'left',
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 20
        }
      }
    }
  };}
```

2) main.html

`<chart [options]="options" ></chart>`

This works for me.

Comment: What happens if you don't have data initially?

Answer (score 0):

Structure of Chart.Options as defined at [codebase](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-chartjs2/blob/master/components/chart.ts#L194) is

```
export interface Options {
    type: Type;
    data: {
      labels: string[];
      datasets: Dataset[];
    };
    options?: {
      tooltips?: {
        custom?: Function;
      };
      legend?: LegendConfiguration;
      scales?: {
        yAxes?: Array<{ticks?: {beginAtZero: boolean}}>
      };
      responsive?: boolean;
      responsiveAnimationDuration?: number;
      maintainAspectRation?: boolean;
      events?: string[];
      onClick?: Function;
      legendCallback?: Function;
      onResize?: Function;
      title?: TitleConfiguration;
      hover?: HoverConfiguration;
      pan?: {
        enabled?: boolean;
        mode?: string;
      },
      zoom?: {
        enabled?: boolean;
        mode?: string;
      }
    };
  }
```

Change the structure of options to the above format to avoid compilation errors.

```
options: Chart.Options = {
   type: , // type of the chart -- mandatory
   data: {}, // mandatory
   options: { //optional
      responsive: true,
      responsiveAnimationDuration: 0
   }
}
```